# PyCryptodome Blowfish algorithm check value

Tags: blowfish

I have tried several goes at checking the output from python PyCryptodome  blowfish algorithm using online test sites. Unfortunately most sites assume the data will be text not binary

I am using simple Blowfish.MODE_ECB encryption for a python27 legacy project. The results are not working which could be the python27 incorrect implementation.

`Cipher key is in hex bytes : c3dedf8f84154aec3a627818634067f1`

`Data to encode in hex bytes : 007e8baf10000000`

`Data output in hex bytes : 361aaca0cce4dd68`

Can anyone confirm the correct output?

Thanks.

MPC

Comment: Use Blowfish test vectors to check your implementation: https://www.schneier.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/vectors-2.txt